# Codeigniter: Error while passsing the response from Google API to db using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am getting data from Google API while loading a view. PHP code of my page to get data is under `<body>`. Now I want to pass this data from view to controller so that I can save it to database.

**Getting response while loading the page. (this code is in view)**

```
$req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=500");
              $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
              $xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());
              $result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');
foreach ($result as $title) {
                echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br>";
                array_push($gmailContacts, $title->attributes()->address);
              }
```

so if I do `print "<pre>" .print_r($result,false). "</pre>";` I can print all the emails on the page.
 AJAX call to save `$gmailContacts` to database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var contacts = <?php echo json_encode($gmailContacts)?>;
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'saveGmailContacts',
            data:contacts,
            type:'POST',
            success: function(msg){

            }

        });
     });
    </script>
```

I am getting `Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: gmailContacts` for the variable

Comment: So what's not working?  Any errors?  If you view source do you see that contacts is getting defined properly in the javascript?

Comment: what do you see on the browser console?

Comment: where is `new Google_HttpRequest` from?

Comment: 1) I see nothing reaching to the database. 2) On browser if prints all the email ids I am getting from google contact api. It means I am getting data from api 3) Google_HttpRequest is from Google's PHP client.

Comment: If the first part of code you have added in on your question is on your controller, you are not passing that variable to the view. Try `$data['gmailContacts']` and passing the `$data` array to the view before you access `$gmailContacts` on your view.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but first part of the code is in view and I want to pass $gmailContacts from view to Controller.

Comment: this looks very strange... why you need to pass data you already have in controller via ajax ? btw, when you load view do you do `$data=array();$data['gmailContacts']=$gmailContacts;$this->load->view('myview',$data);` ?

Comment: I am getting this data as HTTP response and want to save it to db.

Comment: just save it in controller. HTTP response made by php part, why not save it just after receive ?

Comment: How would I save when I receive it? Sorry I am new to CodeIgniter.

Comment: why you doing http request in view ? view is for displaying, not for logic

Comment: Ok. So I am on page1 which ask user if they want to access gmail contacts, if user say yes they will be redirected to page 2 by API.page 2 will have access to api response.

Comment: in controller for page2 make your request and call `$this->mymodel->save($gmailContacts)`

Comment: how would $gmailContacts will reach from page2 to controller at the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23673/discussion-between-eicto-and-himanshu-yadav)